# Управление одним фрагментом из другого

Tags: android, android-fragment

Мне нужно из одного фрагмента получить доступ к методам другого фрагмента.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Можно сделать статическими или переменные с фрагментами, или методы

Answer (score 1):

Абстрактный класс `FragmentManager` управляет фрагментами, логично что вы можете получить объект `Fragment`.
Всё как обычно - кастуем `findFragmentById()` на `FragmentManager` определяем какой фрагмент вам нужен `R.id.myFrag`, приводите к нужному типу фрагмент, чтоб получить доступ(определить правильно ссылку объекта) к вашим public методам объекта. А потом как обычно, myFrag.callMyMethod().

Comment: Можна поподробней ? А то у меня нет метода findFragmentById.

Answer (score 0):

Так как управление ведется фрагментами из **Activity** правильно было бы определять методы в Activity, чтобы потом их можно было вызвать из любого другого фрагмента. Но можно сделать и статические методы, но это грабли. 
Вот так вызываем из фрагмента метод активити:

```
Someactivity aa = (Someactivity)getContex();
aa.nameofmethod();
```

Comment: Из активити я знаю как вызывать. Я сейчас как раз переношу все с активити в фрагмент, потому что сказали что такой подход правильнее.